# asyncio: sleep for sub-millisecond interval

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am building a device based on raspberry PI. It will have several concurrent functions that should work simultaneously. In this case using asyncio looks like a reasonable choice (well, I can write all this stuff in C++ with threads, but python code looks much more compact)

One of the functions is to drive a stepper motor via GPIO pulses. These pulses should be 5-10 microseconds long. Is there a way to get asleep for a sub-milliseconds intervals with asyncio sleep?

Comment: As far as I know, the RPI can produce PWM, you might need to use that instead of sending the signals yourself

Comment: [The comments here](https://amp-reddit-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3wdzc0/microsecond_delay_with_python_for_controlling/?amp_js_v=0.1&usqp=mq331AQECAEoAQ%3D%3D) seems to say that even 100 microseconds is infeasible, regardless of language/OS.

Comment: Well, I do not need super precise timings, but I can do 10-20us pulses no problem in C++. My stepper motor does a full turn at 200 steps * 16 microsteps for 1 second which gives about 10us pulses with 300us delay between them.    As fo PWM - I'll use PWM for other functions, while my stepper motor goes to regular GPIO. Moreover PWM can't guarantee number of pulses generated, only duty cycle.

Comment: have you looked at Pigpio? its a python library that allows finer control of pins.  it works well for servos, and it looks like someone has experimented using it for steppers. https://advpistepper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to get asleep for a sub-milliseconds intervals with asyncio sleep?

On Linux asyncio uses the `epoll_wait` system call, which specifies the timeout in milliseconds, so anything sub-millisecond won't work, despite being able to specify it in `asyncio.sleep()`.

You can test it on your machine by running the following program:

```
import asyncio, os

SLEEP_DURATION = 5e-3  # 5 ms sleep

async def main():
    while True:
        # suspend execution
        await asyncio.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION)
        # execute a syscall visible in strace output
        os.stat('/tmp')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Save the program e.g. as `sleep1.py` and run it under `strace`, like this:

```
$ strace -fo trc -T python3.7 sleep1.py
<wait a second or two, then press Ctrl-C to interrupt>
```

The `trc` file will contain reasonably precise timings of what goes on under the hood. After the Python startup sequence, the program basically does the following in an infinite loop:

```
24015 getpid()                          = 24015 <0.000010>
24015 epoll_wait(3, [], 1, 5)           = 0 <0.005071>
24015 epoll_wait(3, [], 1, 0)           = 0 <0.000010>
24015 stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=45056, ...}) = 0 <0.000014>
```

We see a call to `getpid()`, two calls to `epoll_wait`, and finally the call to `stat`. The first `epoll_wait` is actually relevant, it specifies the timeout in milliseconds, and sleeps for approximately the desired period. If we lower the sleep duration to sub-milliseconds, e.g. 100e-6, `strace` shows that asyncio still requests a 1ms timeout from `epoll_wait`, and gets as much. The same happens with timeouts down to 15 us. If you specify a 14 us or smaller timeout, asyncio actually requests a no-timeout poll, and `epoll_wait` completes in 8 us. However, the second `epoll_wait` also takes 8 us, so you can't really count on microsecond resolution in any form of shape.

Even if you use threads and busy-looping, you are likely to encounter synchronization issues with the GIL. This should likely done in a lower-level language such as C++ or Rust, and even so you'll need to be careful about the OS scheduler.